# Not Fetching JSON data from localhost using React Native

Tags: json, reactjs, react-native

It may be duplicate question, but i tried most of stuffs from internet but no success.
I am new to React Native. I am using physical device(my android phone) as the running my output and tried to get JSON data from one of my testing project coded in PHP in localhost (default port 80).

Here is my Login.js login function to fetch data:

```
login = () => {
    fetch('http://localhost/XTest/send_react', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        username: this.state.username,
        password: this.state.password,
      })
    })
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((res) => {
      if (res.success === true) {
        AsyncStorage.setItem('user', res.user);
        this.props.navigation.navigate('Profile');
      } else {
        alert(res.message);
      }
    })
    .done();
```

I tested my PHP code by loading url above, it is giving JSON data. But all i got in React Native load is :

> Network request failed with bunches of errors codes in Red.

I tried changing my url => 'http:/localhost:80/xxxxxxxxx' and even added "proxy": 'http://localhost/' as suggested somewhere in internet pages, but without any success. Any help or suggestion will be appreciate. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

That's because localhost is local to the device only.
You need the IP address of the actual device running PHP (if it's on the same network it might look like 192.168.x.x) Try `apr -a`in a terminal or command prompt too see the addresses of all devices on the network.

Answer (score 0):

```js
fetch('http://YOURIP(192.168.X.X):YOURPORT', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone facing this issue for the Android Emulator (Genymotion) just make sure you use your local `IP address` following the port `number`. Which you can easily identify using `ipconfig` in your local terminal or command prompt.

My example of an anonymous function in React-Native

```
login = () => {

fetch('http://192.x.x.x:PORT', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: { 'content-type': 'application/json' },
  body: JSON.stringify({ 
      username: this.state.username, 
      password: this.state.password }),
}).then(res => {
  console.log(res)
}).catch(err => {
  console.log(err)
})
  ...etc 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I also have the same problem anyone can find a solution. I tried to use IP address but not given the response. Please look my below code.

```
let email = this.state.email;
let pass = this.state.pass;

fetch("http://192.168.1.2:8080/ReactAPI/post.php", {
      method: "POST",
      body: JSON.stringify({
        email: email,
        password: pass
      }),
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        Accept: "application/json"
      }
    })
      .then(response => console.log(response))
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Answer (score 0):

You may start your server at particular IP...

for eg. in case of json-server,--host [IP-address] will start your server at that location :

```
json-server --watch db.json -p 3001 -d 2000 --host 192.168.83.230
```